# Custom Jquery in admin breaks media-upload script

Tags: admin, jquery, uploads, jquery-ui, thickbox

I have this part of code which loads custom version of jquery

```
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"), false, '');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Everything works fine but if i open the media upload manager which is loaded by this code

```
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
```

and triggered by this

```
                <script language="JavaScript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
                    formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
                    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true');
                    return false;
                    });

                    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
                    imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
                    jQuery('#upload_image').val(imgurl);
                    tb_remove();
                    }

                    });
                </script>
                    <label for="upload_image">
                        <input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="upload_image" value="<?php  ?>" />
                        <input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
                        <br />Enter an URL or upload an image for the banner.
                    </label>
```

The lightbox opens and displays all options, but when i choose "Upload Image" or if i go to media library and select an image from there nothing happens.

If i remove the custom jquery the media uploader works fine.
But then the jquery ui code i have is not working, although i am loading the jquery-ui script, so i have to load my custom latest version of jquery.

Is there any solution so both media-upload and jquery-ui are working on the same page in the plugins admin panel?

Comment: Fix the custom jQuery code?

Comment: What do you mean?By custom version i mean(as shown in the code) that i am loading the latest version of jQuery.
I do not have any jQuery errors in my code.

Comment: I mean the jQuery UI code you have written and that relies on the remote jQuery. Rewrite it until you can use the regular jQuery from WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people think it's a bad practice to deregister/reregister jQuery, despite the performance improvements c/o a CDNed version (and if you're going for a CDN, I see Google's version more often than jQuery's). However, if you're going to do that, you really should only do that on the front-end only so at least the admin can correctly assume that the current WP-preloaded jQuery version is being used.

So switch your script to this and I suspect your problems probably will end:

```
function my_custom_scripts() {
    if( !is_admin() ) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"), false, '');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts' );
```

Comment: Hey thanks, already tried that and as i say to my question when i remove the custom jquery version from admin the media-upload works fine, but then the jquery ui and other jquery scripts i am loading break down.
Those scripts are loaded in the header and it looks like jquery version of wordpress is loaded after them.

Comment: If it's an issue of loading order, you just need to specify the 'jquery' handle for the $deps argument of `wp_enqueue_script()` in your jquery-ui and custom scripts.